# unable to start DSE server

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm using `ubuntu 16.04 LTS`.
I've installed `datastax` with [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installDEBdse.html) procedure.
The very first day it worked perfectly.
But now it's not working. Here's the
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiDxJ.png).

My `debug.log`:

```
ERROR [main] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,951  DseDaemon.java:490 - Unable to start DSE server.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create thrift socket to localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$Factory.buildTServer(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:269) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TServerCustomFactory.buildTServer(TServerCustomFactory.java:46) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer$ThriftServerThread.<init>(ThriftServer.java:131) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer.start(ThriftServer.java:58) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseThriftServer.start(DseThriftServer.java:46) ~[dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:486) [cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:3.0.11.1485]
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.start(DseDaemon.java:485) ~[dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:583) [cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:3.0.11.1485]
at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91) [dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address localhost/127.0.0.1:9042.
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TCustomServerSocket.<init>(TCustomServerSocket.java:75) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$Factory.buildTServer(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:264) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
... 8 common frames omitted
ERROR [main] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,952  CassandraDaemon.java:709 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create thrift socket to localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.start(DseDaemon.java:493) ~[dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:583) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:3.0.11.1485]
at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91) [dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create thrift socket to localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$Factory.buildTServer(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:269) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TServerCustomFactory.buildTServer(TServerCustomFactory.java:46) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer$ThriftServerThread.<init>(ThriftServer.java:131) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer.start(ThriftServer.java:58) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseThriftServer.start(DseThriftServer.java:46) ~[dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:486) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:3.0.11.1485]
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.start(DseDaemon.java:485) ~[dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address localhost/127.0.0.1:9042.
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TCustomServerSocket.<init>(TCustomServerSocket.java:75) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$Factory.buildTServer(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:264) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:5.0.5]
... 8 common frames omitted
INFO  [Daemon shutdown] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,953  DseDaemon.java:577 - DSE shutting down...
DEBUG [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,954  StorageService.java:1210 - DRAINING: starting drain process
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,955  HintsService.java:212 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [Daemon shutdown] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,957  PluginManager.java:347 - Deactivating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.plugin.health.NodeHealthPlugin
INFO  [Daemon shutdown] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,958  PluginManager.java:347 - Deactivating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.plugin.DseClientToolPlugin
INFO  [Daemon shutdown] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,959  PluginManager.java:347 - Deactivating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.plugin.InternalQueryRouterPlugin
INFO  [Daemon shutdown] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,959  PluginManager.java:347 - Deactivating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.leasemanager.LeasePlugin
INFO  [Daemon shutdown] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,962  PluginManager.java:347 - Deactivating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.CqlSlowLogPlugin
INFO  [Daemon shutdown] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,966  PluginManager.java:347 - Deactivating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.metrics.PerformanceObjectsPlugin
INFO  [Daemon shutdown] 2017-01-30 13:54:08,966  PluginManager.java:347 - Deactivating plugin: com.datastax.bdp.plugin.ThreadPoolPlugin
```

Comment: can you check if some cassandra process is hanging by using ps -ef | grep cassandra then kill it and try it again. Also it looks a bit strange that you are trying to start thrift on port 9042 this port is for cql.

Comment: @MarkoŠvaljek thanks MARKO.i was changed rpc_port to 9042.

Comment: no problem man ;) glad I could help